# Bootstrap not working with spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am attempting to install bootstrap for use in my spring boot project, which uses thymeleaf. I am getting this error with the template (index.html, shown below):

```
Malformed markup: Attribute "class" appears more than once in element
```

I assume this is because bootstrap isn't installed properly. Below I have an image of the files also. 
I am pretty sure all the dependencies are right.

INDEX HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
    <script
        src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> -->
    <title>Home</title>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="topnavbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-
                    toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Profile</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/competition">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Competitions
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="/logout"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;
                        <strong>Log out</strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container" class="row">
    <div class="page-header" id="banner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                <img src="ban.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                <div class="sponsor"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container"></div>

</body>

<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var panels = $('.user-infos');
        var panelsButton = $('.dropdown-user');
        panels.hide();

        //Click dropdown
        panelsButton.click(function () {
            //get data-for attribute
            var dataFor = $(this).attr('data-for');
            var idFor = $(dataFor);

            //current button
            var currentButton = $(this);
            idFor.slideToggle(400, function () {
                //Completed slidetoggle
                if (idFor.is(':visible')) {
                    currentButton.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
                    chevron - up
                    text - muted
                    "></i>');
                }
                else {
                    currentButton.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
                    chevron - down
                    text - muted
                    "></i>');
                }
            })
        });


        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        $('button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("This is a demo.\n :-)");
        });
    });

</script>

</html>
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.finalYearProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>student-life</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>student-life</name>
    <description>Jill's Student Life Final Year Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
            8
        </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- upgrade to thymeleaf version 3 -->
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-
            dialect.version>
            <thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-
                extras-springsecurity4.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId1>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The exception will give the line # in the html where the error is occurring... in any case, the actual problem is here:

```
<div class="container" class="row">
```

Thymeleaf won't allow an element to have two attributes with the same name (`Attribute "class" appears more than once in element`).  Just change it to:

```
<div class="container row">
```

Comment: That fixed the error but Bootstrap still isn't working

Comment: It's probably not the css still.  Open your developer tools and see which files are `404`ing and then fix the links to them.

Comment: Due to my "beginnerness", I have no idea how to go about what you're asking in eclipse.....

Comment: Open your application in Chrome or Firefox.  Press F12 to open the developer tools and click on the network tab. Refresh the page, and you should see a list of all the requests your browser is making.  You need to make sure bootstrap is correctly loading (and isn't red with a 404 not found error -- and if it is, you need to correct your links to it).  If that doesn't fix it, you'll have to supply more details (because "Bootstrap still isn't working" without any error messages or other information doesn't really give any clue how to fix the problem).